# How can I fontify a new keyword with special character in Emacs, e.g. like `-let` or `-if` or `*if`?

Tags: font-lock

I already tried but was not successful. Here is the regex:

```
(font-lock-add-keywords 'lisp-mode
                        '(("\\<\\(FIXME\\):" 1 font-lock-warning-face prepend)
                          ("\\<\\(\\_<*if\\_>\\|\\_<-let\\_>\\|*cond\\|fn\\|-fn\\|then\\|do\\|else\\)\\>" . font-lock-keyword-face)))
```

Update: I already tried `[*]` but it didn't work.

```
(font-lock-add-keywords 'lisp-mode
                        '(("\\<\\(FIXME\\):" 1 font-lock-warning-face prepend)
                          ("\\<\\([*]if>\\|let\\|[*]cond\\|then\\|do\\|end\\|else\\|handler-case\\)\\>" . font-lock-keyword-face)))
```

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, but if you want to match a special regexp char such as `*` then you need to escape it, using `[*]` or `\\*`.

Comment: @Drew it doesn't work. I want to match keywords like `*if` or `*let` or `-if` or `-let, but even after escaping Emacs just doesn't highlight the `*` character.

Comment: Please show the code you tried. Did you try `[*]`?

Comment: @Drew I updated the code

Comment: OK. I didn't check anything else about your regexp or question. I just noticed that you used a  special char (`*`) and I guessed that you really wanted to match that char literally. Someone else might help with the more general question.

Comment: In addition to the error I mentioned in my answer, you'll need to quote the face in your "FIXME" line.

Answer (score 1):

When writing regular expressions (in any flavor) one should start small, and build up. So let's do that with Emacs's built in `re-builder`. Given a buffer, containing only the string `(*if foo)` do `M-x re-builder`. The window will split and your focus will move to the new smaller buffer labeled `*RE-Builder*`, with your cursor between the two double quote marks.

Now, input `if`

```
"if"
```

You'll see that the `if` in your larger buffer is highlighted. Add `*` to the beginning of your regex.

```
"*if"
```

You'll see that the `*if` is highlighted now. Wait, what? While `*` is special (zero or more of the previous thing), at the beginning of a regex it means a literal `*`. For example, lets try and match a literal `(*if`

```
"(*if"
```

Now only the `if` is highlighted, because our regex says "match zero or more open parens followed by 'if'". Anyway, back on track. We want to match a literal `*`, so let's be specific.

```
"[*]if"
```

That still matches `*if`. Now, according to your example code, I see you're trying to constrain your matches. That's good, so let's try it here. We'll skip the capturing group for now.

```
"\\<[*]if"
```

Our match now fails. What happened? `\\<` is a special character for "match the beginning of a word". Well, a literal asterisk (`*`) is *not* a word character; our regex is trying to match a thing that cannot exist. It will always fail. Let's swap our "start-of-word" and "literal `*`".

```
"[*]\\<if"
```

We match again. Yay. From here continue to build up your regex in `re-builder`, then add it to `(font-lock-add-keywords)`. Remember when you change your font-lock keywords with `font-lock-add-keywords` (via `M-:` or an interactive elisp buffer), you'll need to re-font-lock your test buffer with `font-lock-fontify-buffer`.